# jQuery mobile Ajax navigation feature and CSS styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, styles

I am creating a website using jQuery Mobile and I am interested in Ajax navigation feature of jQuery Mobile.

My first webpage has some CSS styling in ... tags, while second webpage has *different styles*.

If I don't use ajax navigation of jQuery Mobile, everything is correct; but if I use ajax navigation, CSS styles of second webpage will not load.

How to load styles with ajax navigation enabled? Must I use jQuery to load these styles? Isn't there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading [this page](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html) should help.

Comment: So I have only two ways: 1. Loading CSS styles in every page. 2. Use jQuery to load CSS styles dynamically. Right?

Comment: Or include all the styles in one file and import that in the first page of your JQM app.

Comment: What if I add CSS styles inside `data-role="page"` of every html file?

Comment: Most of the time you will end up with styles that you want to apply across all your pages...